SceneBuilder 23.0.0 for Java won't install on macOS
Interface development in Java environment uses Scene Builder. I am trying to install the latter on a MacBook Pro Intel (Sequoia 15.0) without success; the problem is the same with macOS 10.14 Mojave.
After launching the file "SceneBuilder-23.0.0-amd64.dmg, displaying the license and volume verification window, the SceneBuilder window (orange SceneBuilder icon on the left and Applications folder on the right) is displayed.
However, at this point, the SceneBuilder icon has a round white prohibitory icon.
Dragging this icon into the Applications folder and trying to run it results in the following message :
"The application "SceneBuilder" cannot be opened because it is not supported by this Mac.".
However, version 20.0.0 installs correctly.
What is the reason for this problem and the solution?
Thanks for your help.
Searched the web for this problem: no occurrences.
Successive installations with no results.
Successful installation of the previous version.

As seen in bug #735, now closed, this was the result of an error in the build system, fixed in #736. One solution is to move forward to the early-access asset: SceneBuilder-24.0.0-SNAPSHOT-amd64.dmg, which is correct. Alternatively, revert to version 22.0.0.
Addendum: For reference, release 23.0.1 now includes a working SceneBuilder-23.0.1-amd64.dmg among the available assets.

Thank you for your reassuring reply.
As you suggest, I'm going ahead with an another version.
Best regards from France.
